# Are there any other class singleton methods

Tags: c++, class, singleton

Are there any other class singleton methods than this one?

```
class Foo
{
private:
Foo(){};
~Foo(){};
public:
 static Foo& GetInstance( void )
    {
      static Foo obj;
      return obj;
    }
};
```

This one is great and work for all cases, except that the class constructor will only be called the first time `GetInstance()` is accessed, this causes some issues with `WinMain`,
e.g when there is a file-read on the constructor and the class members value are set from it, like a .ini/.lua configuration

Comment: will it work if you implement another `GetInstance()` that takes an argument (the path to "the .ini/.lua configuration").

Comment: You shouldn't be reading a file in your constructor. Have a method for that.

Comment: I might add another private function `Foo init( /* args */ );` and then have `static Foo obj(init(...));`, so you can have some non-trivial construction logic happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I don't like this way on instantiating the Singleton class. I like to use an `init` function, to explicitly create the class, and a `Done` function to free. Templating also makes everything a little neater. As for loading a file, this should probably be a method of the child class.

```
// Singleton.h
template<class T>
class Singleton
{
  public:
    static void Init() { m_pInst = new T(); }
    static void Done() { delete m_pInst; }
    static T& GetInstance() { assert(m_pInst); return *m_pInst; }
  protected:
    Singleton() {}
  private:
    Singleton(const Singleton&) {}
  private:
    static T* m_pInst;
}

// Foo.h
class Foo : public Singleton<Foo>
{
  public:
    void LoadConfig(const char* path) {} // Load config.
}

// Foo.cpp
Foo* Singleton<Foo>::m_pInst = NULL;
```

Comment: What's the point of this if all the `Init` function does is `new T()`? This doesn't seem to add anything, and the block-static object gets you thread safety and proper ordering for free.

Comment: With C++ 2011 the approach using a local static variable has the advantage of being thread-safe (according to 6.7 [stmt.dcl] paragraph 4).

Comment: Just trying to avoid accessors that do more than they should be doing. The `GetInstance` method should assert that the class has been initialized before it's accessed. OP is concerned that calls to `GetInstance` are constructing the class instance, and this avoids that situation.